# Show a smooth map from a compact, connected, orientable surface to a cyllinder has singular derivative at 2 points.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $M$ be a compact, connected, orientable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let $N$ be the cyllinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $x^2+y^2=1$.  Suppose $f:M\to N$ is $C^{\infty}$.  Show that $f_*:TM\to TN$ is singular at 2 or more points.

So far I've shown $f_*$ is singular at at least one point since otherwise f is surjective.  The argument here is that by the inverse function theorem, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.  A local homeomorphism $f:M\to N$ is an open map and since $M$ is compact, $f(M)$ is therefore both closed and open.  Since $N$ is connected, $f(M)=N$.

To find another point I tried to remove the singular point from $M$ and again use the inverse function theorem, but there is a lot less to work with since $M-\{\text{pt}\}$ is not compact.

Comment: Look at the $z$-component of $f$.

Comment: it is extremely dangerous (and mostly nonsense) to say: "$f(M)$ is therefore both closed and open". Compactness is a property of a topological space (whereas only subsets are open or closed), so you should consider the image $f(M)$ to be compact (as the continous image of a compact space). What does this imply?

Comment: @DanValenzuela Huh?  Compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed.  I don't understand what you are complaining about.

Comment: @DanValenzuela I meant $f(M)$ is both open and closed in $N$, obviously.

Comment: @Seth okay maybe I was to harsh. But if you did so far, then you are almost done. Just add that by the compactness argument $f(M)$ is bounded in the unbounded space $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote the components of $f$ by $f_1,f_2,f_3$.

In particular, $f_3 \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and since $M$ is compact, $f_3$ attains its maximum and minimum at some points of $M$.

What happens at these points?

Comment: Ah, very nice solution.